# How to add a **OUTER POSITIONED** outline to Text Mesh Pro in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, tmp, textmeshpro

I'm looking to find a way to add an outside positioned outline to TMP in Unity. At the moment what I have right now using the outline property gives me an awkward and ugly center position outline.

First image is what I want to achieve and second is what I have in Unity.
[What I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N22ls.png)
[What Unity gives me by default using Outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EehXJ.png)

Please let me know if theres some plugin or way of doing this, thank you.